# Apps won't open links in Chrome even when I set it as default action

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android

Got updated to Jellybean (4.1.2) finally last weekend. Also installed the Chrome browser. Certain apps, like Call Control, open links in the default browser, but don't make the connection with Chrome *even though I specifically clicked "Open with Chrome / Always"* ... just nothing happens.

Had to clear defaults in Chrome and go back to using default browser to open links from apps.

Any reason for this? Any workarounds? I like the Chrome browser otherwise, but if it swallows link requests from other apps it's a non-starter for me.

Comment: Just to be clear, are these "http" links, to web pages (rather than to files you'd want to download)?

Comment: @DanHulme: Yes.